# Integrating TestNG with Cucumber Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

Is there any way to integrate cucumber with existing testng project? Currently, in our project we are using testng with Page object model. Now we decided to include Cucumber also. But i think we cant , because cucumber uses feature file where we can have 'n' number of scenarios. But testng its running based on @test methods.
So, let me know if we can integrate cucumber + testng and if so, how we can run each and every @test methods using cucumber.

Comment: You already know the answer, you have to have feature files to work with cucumber

Comment: Look at this http://sahajamit.github.io/Cucumber-JVM-with-TestNG/... Basically you will have to move code from your test methods to step definitions. What is the logic or benefits of inserting cucumber if you want to continue with existing testng methods?

Answer (score 0):

Running cucumber scenarios/features using TestNG runner is possible and it adds value, but reverse is not. What you want to achieve by running TestNG with cucumber runner? If you want to have descriptive step level report with existing TestNG test you can start using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can integrate Cucumber JVM + Test NG.

You can use the Cucumber JVM at the @Test Method of TestNG. Do not use Main.main of the Cucumber API since there's a System.exit(0) at the end. Instead you can use Main.run of the Cucumber. 
Call the run method in Test method.

```
Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "package", "path of feature file"}, ClassLoader.getClassLoader);
```

The run method requires a classLoader, so generate your own classloader if required.

```
public static byte run(String[] argv, ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException {
          RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions = new RuntimeOptions(new ArrayList<String>(asList(argv)));

        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new MultiLoader(classLoader);
        ClassFinder classFinder = new ResourceLoaderClassFinder(resourceLoader, classLoader);
        Runtime runtime = new Runtime(resourceLoader, classFinder, classLoader, runtimeOptions);
        runtime.run();
        return runtime.exitStatus();
```

}

You can also create your own classLoader to run the main method.